# Offsetting multiple points

Tags: qgis, point, offset

I have a multiline shapefile and a point shapefile. The points are supposed to fall in the center of line breaks but when imported to qgis, the points fall on one end of a line break. Is there a method to center these points? There is way to many to offset individually or selecting several points and using 'move feature' tool.

Here is what QGIS looks like and what the CAD drawing looks like. Im on QGIS 3.10.14

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "the point are supposed to fall"?

Comment: I am referring to the location of the points. So in the CAD drawing the line breaks are filled with a symbol. When exported out the points for those symbols are no longer centered. I hoping someone has a way to offset these points so that they are located in the center of the line breaks.

Comment: This seems like an interesting question, but I am confused: Your image does not help because I can't tell if it is the CAD drawing or QGIS.  It would help if you would show 1) what you have now as shapefiles, 2) what/where is the problem, and 3) what the shapefiles *should* look like.  Also: QGIS version, coordinate reference system of all shapefiles.

Comment: Hi Stu Smith, I have added what the cad drawing looks like and my qgis version. Im assuming the point location in the CAD drawing is on one end of the symbol so when its shapefile is imported to qgis the point is not centered. Im wondering if there is a method to offset these points so that they are centered.